# Determine TTL of stored documents - Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, ttl

I have a bunch of documents stored in couchbase bucket. I want to find the TTL for each document. Is there a way to do it?

EDIT:

I created a view to display the metadata. I assume below is the unix time for expiration.

```
{
   "id": "beer-Milk-New",
   "rev": "9-145c05b4021400005771779102000000",
   "expiration": 1467053969,
   "flags": 33554432
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which version of Couchbase Server, but this answer assumes you are using 4.x and can run a N1QL query.

I think you're on the right track. Check out this blog post on detecting expirations before they happen: http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/april/detecting-expirations-of-documents-with-couchbase-server-and-n1ql

Basically you need two steps. First, create an index on the expiration time.

```
CREATE INDEX iExpiration ON default(exp_datetime) USING GSI;
```

This isn't *strictly* necessary, I don't think, but it will improve the performance.

Second, just run a N1QL query something like below (which will list documents that will expire in the next 30 seconds).

```
SELECT META(default).id, *
FROM default 
WHERE DATE_DIFF_STR(STR_TO_UTC(exp_datetime),MILLIS_TO_UTC(DATE_ADD_MILLIS(NOW_MILLIS(),30,"second")),"second") < 30 
  AND STR_TO_UTC(exp_datetime) IS NOT MISSING;
```

So, if you want to find the TTL for each document, you would probably need to subtract `exp_datetime` from the current time (I believe that's `CLOCK_MILLIS()`).

Comment: Note that `exp_datetime` here must explicitly be added and maintained for each document. Couchbase does not automatically expose the actual TTL via ordinary means.